# Halt alert() in parent window

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile

Let's say I have a a link that open new window.

```
<a href="URL" target="_blank">open new window</a>
```

In the new window I change the URL of the parent to something else:

```
<script type="text/javascript">if(parent.window.opener) parent.window.opener.location='ANOTHERURL';</script>
```

Unfortunately I cannot control what will appear on ANOTHERURL - and sometimes there are javascript alert()s that are causing my browser to go back to that parent window.

Is there any way to block JS alert() running in background while I'm in new window?

All this is meant on mobile phones - in Android and iOS.

Comment: Not unless you control the scripts that are being loaded

Comment: BTW, you don't need to write parent.window.opener, window.opener will directly refer to the 'parent' window: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener

Comment: ANOTHERURL = somescript.php -> that I control - but there is a PHP redirect to another page.

Comment: one more idea is throwing error?